Create DataProduct on Amazon Data Exchange with API
When I try to create new product with API call:
change_set = catalog.start_change_set({
  catalog: 'AWSMarketplace',
  change_set: [
    {
      change_type: 'CreateProduct',
      entity: {
        type: 'DataProduct@1.0',
      },
      details: {
        name: 'FirstProduct'
      }.to_json
    }
  ]
})

I get 2 different messages depending on the account being registered on Data Exchange:
When not registered:
Aws::MarketplaceCatalog::Errors::AccessDeniedExceptioncomamazonawsservicesmarketplacecatalogmodel: Entity type DataProduct@1.0 and change type CreateProduct requires AWS Marketplace registration and a public profile. Please visit https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/management/tour to complete registration.

After registration:
Aws::MarketplaceCatalog::Errors::ValidationExceptioncomamazonawsservicesmarketplacecatalogmodel: [Requested entity type 'DataProduct@1.0' and change type 'CreateProduct' is an invalid combination.]

Can someone help what's the proper combination for creating new product on AWS Data Exchange?
